# Globally Enabling/Disabling HTML Editor Options

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, html-editor

I know it is possible to set options on the Publishing Field HTML Editor, such as the allowance of Fonts, Images etc. However, from what I've read, it seems these can only be applied per control. Is this the case? Is there a simple way of applying these settings as policy across a whole site (collection)? I'm talking MOSS 2007 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Not tried this, so not sure it will work (it should) but you could try the following:

- Create a custom field control which inherits Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.RichHtmlField
- Override the required properties to ensure they always return true/false.
- Deploy it
- Amend your page layouts to use this control instead (where required)

Alternatively as Marc says Telerik's control is good and they do a freebie version if you have a MOSS Standard licence.  Its the last one on this page:

http://www.telerik.com/community/free-products.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Telerik's Rich Text Editor for SharePoint](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/sharepoint.aspx).  I used it quite a while back on a project and it gave me great granularity of control as well as nice new functionality.